# How to find folders where name contain strings

Tags: find, sh, busybox

EDIT:
Found a possible solution, see lower, but I also need some help to make it faster.

I want to dig inside a folder that contain folders and copy each folder that the name contain some strings, but I'm pretty stuck.
For now the structure that I came with is:

```
#!/opt/bin/sh

EXCLUSIVECOUNTRIES="it,ch"
ONLYFROMCOUNTRIES=$(echo $EXCLUSIVECOUNTRIES | tr "," "\n")
FORCEPROTOCOL= # can be tcp udp or empty, that catch both

if [ $(echo "$FORCEPROTOCOL" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') == "tcp" ]; then # tcp protocol
    PROTOCOL="tcp"
elif [ $(echo "$FORCEPROTOCOL" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') == "udp" ]; then
    PROTOCOL="udp"
else
    PROTOCOL="\w"
fi

for dirz in $(find /opt/serverconfigs/ -type d | grep -Ei $PROTOCOL); do
    if [ ! -z $ONLYFROMCOUNTRIES ]; then # exclusive contry present, copy only what I need
        echo "cp "$dirz" to
    else # no exclusive contry, so copy all
        for country in $ONLYFROMCOUNTRIES; do # for each contry
            if [ $(echo $(basename "$dirz") | sed -En 's/^([a-z\-]+).*/\1/p') == "$country" ]; then
                echo "$dirz"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

But when I run it I got

```
sh: ch: unknown operand
cp /opt/serverconfigs/de0515udp to
sh: ch: unknown operand
cp /opt/serverconfigs/de0119udp to
sh: ch: unknown operand
cp /opt/serverconfigs/nl-uk0002tcp to
sh: ch: unknown operand
cp /opt/serverconfigs/us2062udp to
sh: ch: unknown operand
cp /opt/serverconfigs/us3415udp to
sh: ch: unknown operand
```

My folder structure is:

```
/opt/serverconfigs/br0031tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/be0097udp
/opt/serverconfigs/uk1088tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/us3270udp
/opt/serverconfigs/ca0313tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/tw-hk0003tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/ro0036tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/uk1004udp
/opt/serverconfigs/us3242tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/uk1174tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/nl0294udp
/opt/serverconfigs/ro0034tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/dk0120tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/us3129tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/us2491tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/ca0075tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/uk1009udp
/opt/serverconfigs/us3188tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/it0081tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/ca0378udp
/opt/serverconfigs/au0216udp
/opt/serverconfigs/us2283tcp
/opt/serverconfigs/us3293tcp
```

The first problem is that seems to work inside-out and I don't see why and the second problem is unknown operand, maybe are connected?
I searched a bit for unknown operand and seem a sh problem with [] and $(), but every time I try to make it works, the result is the same

What I do wrong?

My expectation is to find all folder where the name contain EXCLUSIVECOUNTRIES var combined with the protocol and copy the folder to another position

Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to shellcheck and some tweak I found a solution that works

```
#!/opt/bin/sh

EXCLUSIVECOUNTRIES="it,ch"
ONLYFROMCOUNTRIES=$(echo $EXCLUSIVECOUNTRIES | tr "," "\n")
FORCEPROTOCOL="" # can be tcp udp or empty, that catch both

if [ "$(echo "$FORCEPROTOCOL" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')" = 'tcp' ]; then # tcp protocol
    PROTOCOL="tcp"
elif [ "$(echo "$FORCEPROTOCOL" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')" = 'udp' ]; then # udp protocol
    PROTOCOL="udp"
else  # both protocols
    PROTOCOL="\w"
fi

for dirz in $(find /opt/serverconfigs/ -type d | grep -Ei $PROTOCOL); do
    if [ -n "$ONLYFROMCOUNTRIES" ]; then # exclusive country present, copy only what I need
        for country in $ONLYFROMCOUNTRIES; do # for each country
            if [ "$(echo "$(basename "$dirz")" | sed -En 's/^([a-z\-]+).*/\1/p')" = "$country" ]; then
                echo "$dirz"
            fi
        done
    else # no exclusive country, so copy all
        echo "cp $dirz to"
    fi
done
```

The problem is that is pretty slow, any way to make it better?
I've to search inside more than 9k folders

Comment: yes it's slow, on each dirz you run grep, basename, and sed. Perhaps you can look for only one awk!

Comment: @ctac_ Thanks. Actually I don't know how to make it in one single line I can try. I'm converting this from a php script, that is really fast to make the directory structure but really slow to parse and download directly from webpage, so I've 2 way, try to find a solution with sh (but I've to install unzip (not so good)) or try to find a way to parse zip content without unzip it in php. So I don't know what can be the best solution